# Get clickable mouse point of UIAutomationElement in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation, ui-automation

I am using the UIAUtomationClient in VBA. I tried this before but for some reason it doesn't work anymore. I'm trying to get the clickable points on a uiautomationelement.

This is my code in the Automation module.

```
Function GetMousePoint(element As IUIAutomationElement) As tagPOINT
    Dim getPoint As Variant
    getPoint = element.GetClickablePoint(GetMousePoint)
End Function
```

And this is my code in the Main module. importBtn is the UIAutomationElement.

```
Dim clickAPI As tagPOINT
clickAPI = Automation.GetMousePoint(importBtn)
```

I keep getting the Compile Error, ByRef Argument Type Mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the priority for UIAutomation in the References UI.